# Charts iOS I have used LineCharts in iOS but after upgrading to swift 4 Charts removed date from bottom

Tags: swift4, ios-charts

[image]

After swift 4 upgrade it is not showing dates here at bottom.

Before it was showing like below.
[image]

After converting my code to swift 4(Xcode 9.2) date just disappear from my data. I have passed my dates array here as:

```
// x-Axis Setup months
self.lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = IndexAxisValueFormatter(values: ["12 Jan", "14 Feb", "8 Mar", "23 Apr"])
```

Answer (score 2):

Hey I found solution for this after a long days. To fix this, use this line in your Podfile.

```
pod 'Charts', '3.0.4'
```

It works by doing this.

Now 3.1.1 resolved this issue you can directly install latest one.

Comment: Any way I could as you some questions about using dates in line charts on the XAxis?